# Auto remove an html attribute from a site I don't own

Tags: automation, html

I am using a site that hosts it's videos via iframe on vimeo. For some reason they disabled Picture in picture mode which I really need. I can reenable this feature by removing an html attribute via devtools locally. Is there a good way to automate this process.

Note: The "dev" of the site is not capable of making any changes on their end. I only need to remove this attribute once it hits my browser

Edit: The tag I need to edit an attribute of is a video tag. I use chrome but any browser will do. OS is Windows 10

Comment: Besides Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey (below), it also may be worth checking out [Violentmonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information about the HTML in question, the
specific tag that needs to be removed, your browser and
operating system, here is a general answer.

You may use the browser add-on
[Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)
to modify the HTML code before it executes.
For Chrome the extension is called
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

This is basically JavaScript code, called userscript, that's injected
into the HTML and can modify almost all aspects of the document.

For a more specific answer, please give more information.